# Export flash file frames as images

Tags: swf

I have a flash (.swf) file consisting of 10 frames. Note that this is not a flash video file (.flv)

Each frame is composed of 50 separate objects that are positioned appropriately (either manually or via tweening).

Is there a tool that will allow me to export the swf so that each frame is exported as a single, final image? Basically, I should be able to take a swf file and convert it to a gif by exporting each frame individually as images and then putting them into a sequence.

I am only interested in converting a frame into an image.

I have tried `swfrender`, part of the [SWFTools suite](http://www.swftools.org/), as follows

```
swfrender -o out.png myfile.swf
```

Which will try to export each frame as an image, so you might get

```
out-1.png
out-2.png
out-3.png
```

With the above command, assuming there are 3 frames.

This does what I want, except it doesn't seem to be able to process my swf correctly, with these warning messages

```
Warning: Shape doesn't start with a moveTo
```

So presumably the technique they're using to build a frame is not working 100% of the time. However, flash players are able to build frames correctly, so there should be a way to build a frame from the data and then export it.